# If i execute the same test case two times, is there a way to generate report.html with a timestamp in the file name?

Tags: robotframework

I have a question related with report.html that maybe someone could help me to clarify

If i execute the same test case two times, is there a way to generate report.html with a timestamp in the file name so after 2 executions i have 2 reports.html.

for example:
report_20200529_15:00:00.html
report_20200529:15:05:00.html

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [timestamping output files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#timestamping-output-files):

> All output files listed in this section can be automatically timestamped with the option --timestampoutputs (-T). When this option is used, a timestamp in the format YYYYMMDD-hhmmss is placed between the extension and the base name of each file.